# php-fpm available default modules. Which?

Tags: php, nginx

I have read a few guides describing the use of nginx with php-fpm. They make a really good team.

Some guides will install like this:

`sudo apt install php-fpm -y`

Some other guides included php modules during installation, mainly a variation of this:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring zip unzip`

My question is, if I omit the modules like the first method, which php modules are installed by default? Which are not?

**Basically, I can't find something online that sates:**

> If you don't explicitly type the php modules to be included, only
>   these will be included.

Comment: Not all guides are made the same, if something need curl you need to install it.

Comment: dont forget you can do `sudo apt install php-{fpm,cli,curl,gd,mysql,mbstring}`

Comment: Ok. So the best way to find out would be to install php-fpm and nothing more. Then, when I configure nginx, I create a `php_info()` page and view modules installed. Correct?

Comment: yeah, or run something like `dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php`

Comment: Beautiful. This is it. Works for any package.